# Update element text using custom binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm making my first custom binding. I would like to be able to specify what text that appears on an element based on a resource file. Something like this:

```
var exampleResource = {
    hello: 'world'
};

ko.bindingHandlers.resource = {

    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {

        var value = valueAccessor();

        ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function() { 
            return exampleResource[value] || '';
        });
    }

};

<span data-bind="resource: 'hello'"></span>
```

Should I use `ko.bindingHandlers.text` as above?

Since the resource variable isn't observable, is there any point of adding the `update` callback for the binding? If I understand it correctly it will only get called if an observable is passed as the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need an `update` if you want to support the input for your binding handler to be dynamic. In your example you don't do that, but you *could*. Here's an example:

```js
var exampleResource = {
    hello: 'world',
    goodbye: 'drowl'
};

ko.bindingHandlers.resource = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var key = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function() { 
            return exampleResource[key] || key;
        });
    }
};

ko.applyBindings({ myObs: ko.observable('goodbye') });
```

```css
span { font-weight: bold; color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

Static: <span data-bind="resource: 'hello'"></span>
<hr>
Dynamic: <span data-bind="resource: myObs"></span>
- based on: <select data-bind="value: myObs, options: ['hello', 'goodbye']"></select>
```

If you don't need this dynamicness you could stick to your old solution. However, in that case I'd question the added value of KnockoutJS for resources in general :-)

Comment: Thank you. My other thought was to add a method to my view models which fetched the resouce data, but it didn't feel DRY to add it on all of them. I guess I could go with prototypical inheritance in that case. Do you see any other solutions?

Comment: If I was developing an ASP.NET app or something similar, I would have used the existing resource handling. But this is a single page app with only javascript involved, so my plan is to make knockout handle it. I guess it's just a question of how to map the static data to the UI in my case...

Comment: Seems like https://github.com/tfsjohan/Knockout-Localization-Binding/blob/master/src/ko.localizationbinding.js is on the same track, right? :)

Comment: Ah, yeah with a SPA that makes some more sense. And that Github repro has the same idea indeed, it seems. I didn't know about it but at first glance it looks like a more fleshed out version indeed.